# Loop trough an array of array using find function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to find a specific object with the name that I'm looking for. For example if I have this data structure:

```
colors = 
    [
        name1:{
            name:stuff,
            (...)
        },
        name2:{
            name:otherstuff,
            (...)
        }
    ]
```

And now I want to find the object with name = stuff I would do the following:

```
const findstuff = colors.find(f => f.name === "stuff")
```

But now imagine I have a wrapping array:

```
colors = [
    [
        name1:{
            name:stuff,
            (...)
        },
        name2:{
            name:otherstuff,
            (...)
        }
    ],
    [
        name3:{
            name:morestuff,
            (...)
        },
        (...)
    ]
]
```

How can I loop trough the first array to reach the second and do a similar find function?

Comment: The `colors` structure you've shown is invalid, you can't put property names inside an array literal (`[]`). Please update the question with syntactically-valid data structures so we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: Unless `colors` is part of an Object (show us...), you should use `colors =`, and not `colors :`.
So you are saying that `colors` is an Array, fine - of what?  As it is shown, it will be an "Array of Errors"...  I'm assuming you mean to have an Array of Objects - if so, wrap `name1:{...}` with curly-braces as such: `{name1:{...}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `flat`:

```
const findstuff = colors.flat().find(f => f.name === "stuff")
```

Comment: About `flat` - I just learned that the default is one-level flattening...
You can specify how deep to flatten with `flat(levels)`.
I just use `flat(Infinity)`...

Comment: @thedude thank you for your answer, it does work. I did however a workaround for it because `flat()` is not supported in IE. I used `colors.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []).find(c => c.name === "stuff")`

Answer (score 0):

@thedude's answer is correct, but only finds the *first* entry with that name.

This returns an array of all items named 'stuff':

```js
colors.flat().filter(item => item.name === 'struff')
```

Comment: About `flat` - I just learned that the default is one-level flattening... You can specify how deep to flatten with `flat(levels)`. I just use `flat(Infinity)`...